# can I get onChange length each input value using useForm in React

Tags: reactjs, react-forms, use-form

i want to this.
create input row when i click ADD HEADLINE button.
and remove input row when i cancel button.
create button is ok but cancel button is not work.
and then, i want to show onChange text count when i input each time.
why this code is not work...?
please help me.

i want to this.
create input row when i click ADD HEADLINE button.
and remove input row when i cancel button.
create button is ok but cancel button is not work.
and then, i want to show onChange text count when i input each time.
why this code is not work...?
please help me.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import InputX from '../../../../../../assets/icons/InputX.svg';

function Headlines({ register }) {
  const [headerLineCount, setHeaderLineCount] = useState([
    { id: 1, inputValue: '' },
  ]);
  const [changeValue, setChangeValue] = useState();

  const countRef = useRef(1);
  const addInput = () => {
    countRef.current += 1;
    setHeaderLineCount(
      headerLineCount.concat({ id: countRef.current, inputValue: changeValue })
    );
  };
  const onRemove = () => {
    setHeaderLineCount(
      headerLineCount.filter(data => data.id !== headerLineCount.id)
    );
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <List>
        <LabelBox>
          <HeadlineLabel htmlFor="headlines">Headlines</HeadlineLabel>
          <Count>{headerLineCount.length}/15</Count>
        </LabelBox>
        {headerLineCount.map(count => (
          <InputWrap key={count.id}>
            <InputBox>
              <Input
                ref={countRef}
                placeholder="New headline"
                maxLength="30"
                {...register(`headlines${count.id}`, {
                  required: true,
                  maxLength: 30,
                })}
                onChange={e => setChangeValue(e.target.value.length)}
              />
              <XIcon src={InputX} onClick={onRemove} value={count.id} />
            </InputBox>
            <TextIndicater>{changeValue}/30</TextIndicater>
          </InputWrap>
        ))}
      </List>
      <AddHeadLine onClick={addInput} disabled={!(headerLineCount.length < 15)}>
        ADD HEADLINE
      </AddHeadLine>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Headlines;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `onRemove` to accept the id you want to remove, and replace `headerLineCount.filter(data => data.id !== headerLineCount.id)`.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import InputX from '../../../../../../assets/icons/InputX.svg';

function Headlines({ register }) {
  const [headerLineCount, setHeaderLineCount] = useState([
    { id: 1, inputValue: '' },
  ]);
  const [changeValue, setChangeValue] = useState();

  const countRef = useRef(1);
  const addInput = () => {
    countRef.current += 1;
    setHeaderLineCount(
      headerLineCount.concat({ id: countRef.current, inputValue: changeValue })
    );
  };
  // added an argument here
  const onRemove = (id) => {
    setHeaderLineCount(
      // Changed this to verify against the argument
      headerLineCount.filter(data => data.id !== id)
    );
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <List>
        <LabelBox>
          <HeadlineLabel htmlFor="headlines">Headlines</HeadlineLabel>
          <Count>{headerLineCount.length}/15</Count>
        </LabelBox>
        {headerLineCount.map(count => (
          <InputWrap key={count.id}>
            <InputBox>
              <Input
                ref={countRef}
                placeholder="New headline"
                maxLength="30"
                {...register(`headlines${count.id}`, {
                  required: true,
                  maxLength: 30,
                })}
                onChange={e => setChangeValue(e.target.value.length)}
              />
              {/* Changed this to pass the id of the currently being processed count */}
              <XIcon src={InputX} onClick={() => { onRemove(count.id) }} value={count.id} />
            </InputBox>
            <TextIndicater>{changeValue}/30</TextIndicater>
          </InputWrap>
        ))}
      </List>
      <AddHeadLine onClick={addInput} disabled={!(headerLineCount.length < 15)}>
        ADD HEADLINE
      </AddHeadLine>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Headlines;
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept my answer if it fixed the problem :)

Comment: I  have a one more trouble. when I click add input row , i want to get how many input text(text.length) . but changeValue is not work...TT

Comment: I wonder if your issue might be `concat` - that's for merging two arrays, but you're actually adding an object to an array. Try replacing `headerLineCount.concat` with `headerLineCount.push`